# How to construct a tuple of non-movable non-copyable objects?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

Is it possible to construct such a `tuple` somehow?

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

auto generate()
{
    // Funktion which constructs a tuple on one line...
    return std::make_tuple(A{},A{});
}

int main()
{
    auto t = generate();
}
```

Is this possible in C++14 and is this possible in C++17 which forces Return-Value-Optimization (unnamed prvalue return expression)??

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7806dcb698f6b0a6)

Comment: "*will this be possible in C++17*" You say "will" as though C++17 was not nearly 2 years old and (mostly) supported by the major compilers at this point.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Because of guaranteed elision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is not always guaranteed though, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hA1WNtNyNbo . But in this particular case you are right.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yeah your comment made it seem like it was an outlandish, crazy notion. When it fact it is true (on paper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tuple`'s constructor that initializes the objects from arguments of the exact same types as the `tuple`'s template parameters requires that the types are copy-constructible. However, if all of the types are default-constructible, then you can do that. So you could just have `generate` issue a `return tuple<A, A>{};`. This works in C++17.

If you want to initialize them with a value, then you can use the `tuple` constructor that uses explicit conversion from a sequence of types that aren't the same as the `tuple` parameters. There, you can use C++17 guaranteed copy elision, but only if the source types use an `operator Type()` overload and follow the rules of guaranteed elision.

Comment: Broken in MSVS 2017 though. I had to abandon my non-copyable/non-moveable stream-like type being generated in a nice function because VS refused to elide the return. So I wouldn't rely on this just yet. (Though MSVS 2019 is out now so we're getting there!)

Answer (score 2):

```
std::tuple<A,A> generate() { return {}; }
```

If you need to non-default construct `A`:

```
template<class U, class F>
struct maker_t{ operator U(){ return f(); } F f; };
template<class U, class F>
maker_t<U,std::decay_t<F>> maker(F&& f){ return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
```

Now you can:

```
std::tuple<A,A> generate() {
  return {
    maker<A>( []{ return A{}; } ),
    maker<A>( []{ return A{}; } )
  };
}
```

where those lambdas can do anything that returns an `A`.

Comment: seems like it still involves move semantics, see gcc 11 here https://godbolt.org/z/eaWzch94o `error: use of deleted function 'A::A(A&&)'` in `generate()` function.

Comment: @MarcinTarsier In gcc.  [Clang accepts it fine](https://godbolt.org/z/zT7fdeEaY).  I believe gcc wrong and clang correct, but I could be wrong.